# how to integrate The Coupon Script in magento

Tags: coupon, script, integrate

I am using magento 1.9.2.4 and i want to integrate The Coupon Script in my site. I want to know about steps to integrate this scrip in my site . Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$minTotal = 1;
$discount = 15;
$numberOfDays = 7;
$couponCode = 'tes-code';

$discountType = Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_FIXED_ACTION;

$todaysdate = date('Y/m/d');
$expirycoupondate = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($todaysdate . "+" . $numberOfDays . " days"));
$_websiteIds = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->getAllIds(); 
$customerGroups = array(0, 1,2,3);
$salesrule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');

$conditions = array(
    '1' => array(
        'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
        'aggregator' => 'all',
        'value' => 1,
        'new_child' => null
    ),
    '1--1' => array(
        'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_address',
        'attribute' => 'base_subtotal',
        'operator' => '>=',
        'value' => $minTotal
    )
);

try {
    $salesrule->setName('Discount Offers')
        ->setDescription('Discount Offers')
        ->setIsActive(1)
        ->setWebsiteIds($_websiteIds)
        ->setCustomerGroupIds($customerGroups)
        ->setCouponType(Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC)
        ->setCouponCode($couponCode)
        ->setUsesPerCoupon(1)
        ->setUsesPerCustomer(1)
        ->setFromDate($todaysdate)
        ->setToDate($expirycoupondate)
        ->setStoreLabels(array(0 => 'Discount Offers.'))
        ->setSimpleAction($discountType)
        ->setDiscountAmount($discount);

    $data = $salesrule->getData();
    $data['conditions'] = $conditions;

    $salesrule->loadPost($data);
    $salesrule->save();

 } catch (Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```